# RPi using RF24 library tmrh20 failing make examples_RPi for ./gettingstarted

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to use the library found here:

https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/RPi.html

I am running an RPi 2 B+ with Raspbian current 11/12/15

I have the example working on Arduino and I have no issues communicating Arduino to Arduino. However when attempting to use the RPi example I end up with this error.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/rf24 $ cd rf24libs/RF24/examples_RPi/
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/rf24/rf24libs/RF24/examples_RPi $ make
g++ -Ofast -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv6zk -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -Wall -I../ -lrf24-bcm transfer.cpp -o transfer
transfer.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
transfer.cpp:129:10: error: ‘sleep’ was not declared in this scope
  sleep(2);
      ^
Makefile:32: recipe for target 'transfer' failed
make: *** [transfer] Error 1
```

The instructions are incredibly simple:

```
wget http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24Installer/RPi/install.sh 
chmod +x install.sh
./install.sh
cd rf24libs/RF24/examples_RPi  
make  
sudo ./gettingstarted
```

So I would expect something that is "out of the box" to function normally correct? Apparently not...

I also have the library that is required for the build, found here:

http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/

I have it installed and ready to go. But in order to continue I need to be able to get this basic gettingstarted example to function. I am new to using GPIO but I have followed the diagram on this page:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22490/rf24-communication-with-arduino

TL;DR

I cannot get the basic example to function based off code found in a well documented and commonly used library using RF24 modules utilizing RPi and the gettingstarted example included in the library.

I invite you to download this and try installing it yourselves on your RPi to see if we all have the same issues. Maybe we can solve this once and for all.

Any help will be much appreciated and I will be monitoring this thread.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following include below the existing includes in transfer.cpp... It'll look like this...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <RF24/RF24.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Afterwords verify that sleep is lowercase:

```
if (role == role_ping_out){
        sleep(2);
        printf("Initiating Basic Data Transfer\n\r");
```

Should compile now...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Sorry, meant to break out that you want to add 

#include <unistd.h> 

to the existing includes (I showed the entire include block for the transfer.cpp file). I had just downloaded the library myself lastnight and came across your issue, that's how I resolved the issue with the compiler.

Comment: I haven't had time to compile it using your corrections yet. It's just been a stick in my side for the work I'm trying to do lol. I'll mark you as an answer just as soon as I get back to it. Thx again for your reply